# Why am I getting permission denied 401 with simple firebase post request - Firebase Security Rules - REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Hi I have the following rest api post (.post() call) to the firebase realtime DB:
https://myapp-app.firebaseio.com/orders.json?auth=xyz
with body:

```
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "type": "123",
    "ownerId": "39LUW3WNtzV3t5pyij81km5Bfe02"
}
```

security rule in firebase:

```
"orders": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
      ".write": "newData.child('ownerId').val() === auth.uid",
      ".indexOn": "ownerId"
    },
```

in other words if you want to create a new order then the logged in user must be set as ownerId of that new order.

It always fails when I post from my site. Yes I have triple checked that the ownerId is equal to the auth.uid.

My only thought was that somehow the types of the values mismatched but they are just both alpha numeric strings, so I dont see how.

This is the first time I have ever tried to match newData property like this with the auth.uid - in my other rules they are usually '$uid === auth.id' checks for update type calls, and this always works.

However, when I copy and paste the exact same data into the firebase rules playground it passes!

I cant figure it out.

Comment: Still haven't figured this out!!